# Write ErrorLogs in a Text file

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops

We have a Web application and deployed in Azure. In our code, we are writing exceptions in a text file by creating date wise files.

While running locally, the text is creating and in Azure, it's not creating.

Do we need to enable any permissions, to create a file and write logs in to it?

Comment: are you deploying our app on app service?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar yes, Web app on app service plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where you are trying to write too, because you only have certain areas per se that you can write too.

Also, if you are deploying a folder that you want to write too, make sure that you have something in it before you deploy because empty folders may not get deployed.

There are other posts on here as well, but using Server.MapPath("~/myfolder_or_otherfolder/") should not require you to have any special privs